# sorting items in python

Tags: python, string

Good day everyone,
               I need help with sorting and writing a sorting function in python. I am trying to write a function `insert_in_order` which takes a list of strings *items* and a string *item*. I'm trying to do this assuming that *items* is already sorted in alphabetical order and i must insert *item* into the correct position in *items*

Also

in regards to the same problem i am facing, i also want to right a function `remove` which takes a list *items* and a string *item*. This function should remove the first occurrence of *item* in *items*. Also, if *item* does not occur at all in *items*, the function should leave *items* unchanged.

Edit:

my original set of functions is as follows

```
def read_list(fname):
    items = []
    with open(fname, 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            items = insert_in_order(items, line[:-1])

    return items


def write_list(items, fname):
    fout = open(fname, 'w')
    for item in items:
        fout.write(item + '\n')
    fout.close()
```

and i also have a test file which is supposed to test those functions:

```
class TestLabThre(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_read_list(self):
        self.assertEqual(
                read_list('lab06ReadTest.txt'),
                ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

def test_write_list(self):
    write_list(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'lab06WriteTest.txt')
    in_file = open('lab06WriteTest.txt', 'r')
    self.assertEqual(in_file.read(), 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n')
```

my `insert_in_order` and `remove` functions are supposed to be added to the functions so that when i run my tests, they pass. But i get a "failed test" every time.

I'm really confused and any help pointing me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use [bisect.insort_left](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort_left) to insert an item `x` into a list `a`, and keep it sorted assuming `a` is sorted.

Use [list.remove](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to remove the first occurence of value from a list. This function raises a ValueError if the value is not in the list. So you'll need to wrap the call in a `try..except` to handle the exception -- see below for an example.

---

```
import bisect

cheese = sorted('manchego stilton brie gouda'.split())
print(cheese)
# ['brie', 'gouda', 'manchego', 'stilton']

item = 'gorgonzola'
bisect.insort_left(cheese, item)
print(cheese)
# ['brie', 'gorgonzola', 'gouda', 'manchego', 'stilton']

try:    
    cheese.remove('manchego')
except ValueError: 
    pass
print(cheese)
# ['brie', 'gorgonzola', 'gouda', 'stilton']
```

Comment: Why don't you use `bisect.bisect_left` to find the position of the item and then `list.pop` to remove it. This will make search `log(n)`, not `O(n)`?

Comment: [Deleting an item from a Python list is O(n)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), so whether we use `list.pop` or `list.remove` we are still O(n).

Comment: Yeah. But then why use `bisect` at all?

Comment: The OP has a list. Insertion and deletion from the list is going to be O(n). Conversion to a blist will be O(n). So all solutions at best will be O(n). `bisect.insort_left` does precisely what the OP asked for, and since it is [written in C](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/504eed5a82a3/Modules/_bisectmodule.c#l180) it will run faster than a Python loop.

Comment: in my case, is "cheese" equal to "items" or "item"? @unutbu

Comment: @AkumaUkpo: `cheese` would be `items` since they are both a list of strings.

Comment: @unubtu okay thanks, i added the function you gave me to my functions but my test still failed. look at the edit in my post. Maybe i didn't write the functions completely or incorrectly. My tests are supposed to pass when i test them but they fail each time.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your sorting problem, a quick solution which requires no additional modules (which may not be computationally optimal, but good enough in many cases):

```
>>> your_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> your_list.append('baa')
>>> your_list.sort()
>>> print your_list
['a', 'b', 'baa', 'c']
```

For removing items, just use the list's `remove` method with an exception handler, as described in [@unutbu's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15856055/709852) solution.

Comment: i'm trying to implement that in a function format. please look at my edit (in my original post)

Comment: So write a function. I feel perhaps you should go back and read some tutorials if you can't manage to write a function by yourself; that's pretty basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`bisect`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module which finds the position of insertion or deletion in sorted list.

Also, note, that insertions and deletions in `list` is `O(n)` as they require to shift all the items to the right of the place of insertion or deletion. You may look into [`blist`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) module to use instead of `list` which performs these operations in `O(log(n))`.